# Checking a Y-m-d date against a closing date

Tags: php, sql

I'm working on a web site that handles job applications. Applications are held in a SQL database, each has a closing date in the format 2013-04-07.

The SQL uses the following WHERE clause to determine if the closing date has passed:

```
WHERE closing_date < NOW()
```

(where 'closing_date' is drawn from the database in the format described above.)

Users have been experiencing problems applying for positions, because the site has been telling them the closing date has passed, a number of hours before midnight at the end of the actual closing date.

Would I be better using CURDATE() instead of NOW() in the SQL statement to determine whether users can submit applications?

Answer (score 0):

You may try it this way

```
WHERE date(closing_date) < date(NOW())
```

Comment: Thanks, could you explain why?

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.